# How to create a date column not nullable?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'm using sqlite. I need to create a `date` column `not nullable`. I try it, but not working.

```
return knex.schema.table("my_table", (table) => {
  table.date("important_day").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
});
```

With this code, I received this error message:

> Unhandled rejection Error: `SQLITE_ERROR`: Cannot add a column with non-constant default.
>   Knex:warning - migrations failed with error: alter table `minisermao` add column `diaminisermao` date not null default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - SQLITE_ERROR`: Cannot add a column with non-constant default

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed for create table we have a ok result:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("foo", function(tb){
    tb.date("xpto").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {  
  return knex.schema.dropTable("foo");
};
```

however for alter table operations it gives us an error.

if possible, try the following:

make a migrate to drop the current table:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("foo");
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) { 
  return knex.schema.createTable("foo", function(tb){
    tb.date("xpto").notNullable().defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  }); 
};
```

then make a second migrate to create the table again.

i suggest such approach because if the project are installed in production, it will not be a healthy approach to change already executed migrations.

hope it helps.

UPDATE:

the very same alter table works flawlessly on postgresql.